# Why am I getting an high limit switch error code on my HVAC when the switch is working?

Tags: hvac

I have a Goodman gms9 and recently it has been not starting intermittently, then giving a high limit switch code. I have checked the high limit switch and it is functioning appropriately. If I leave it alone the furnace will eventually start, or I shut off the power for a minute and when I turn it back on it will work. The filter is clean and all ducts/registers are clear and open. What could be causing the intermittent problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try jumpering the high limits out (this is a jumper between the pink and blue wires exiting the main control board) and seeing if that causes the high limit code to go away.  If it does, then you have a loose/bad connection in the high limit wiring.  If it doesn't, then the control board's sick and should be replaced.  Either way, don't forget to pull the troubleshooting jumper out when you're done with it!

Answer (score 1):

Check for an intermittently bad fan relay (i.e. the blower sometimes fails to start, causing the furnace to overheat when that occurs).

Answer (score 0):

Furnace lasts > 10 years, natural gas process had been improving, higher heat ecoefficiency. Faster heat up.

Increase heat fan-off time, and decrease heat fan-on time (to better cool off the heat unit), solves most of the problem (limit switch error, when the switches are tested ok)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).